# Getting ListBox Items Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, visualtreehelper

I have tried to get the listbox items using VisualTreeHelper class. When I do VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount((DependencyProperty)listBox1) it returns count as 0. But the listbox has lot of listboxitems in it.Can someone let me know if I am doing any mistake?

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the ItemContainerGenerator property of the Listbox class ? It has some methods you can use to retrieve Listbox items.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator(v=VS.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)